# Summation of inverse Fisher Information matrix

Tags: estimation, unbiased-estimator, fisher-information

[I deleted my previous question, which was wrong]

Define:
$\boldsymbol\theta=[\theta_1,~ \theta_2]^T.$
With both $\theta_1, \theta_2$ scalars. The FIM is given by:
$\mathbf{J}_{\theta\theta}=\begin{bmatrix}{J}_{\theta_1\theta_1}&{J}_{\theta_1\theta_2}\\{J}_{\theta_1\theta_2}&{J}_{\theta_2\theta_2}\end{bmatrix}.$

I know that the CRLB (Cramer Rao lower bound) is then given by:

$CRLB(\theta_1)=[\mathbf{J}^{-1}_{\theta\theta}]_{1,1},$

$CRLB(\theta_2)=[\mathbf{J}^{-1}_{\theta\theta}]_{2,2},$

My question: what is the meaning of

$[\mathbf{J}^{-1}_{\theta\theta}]_{1,1}+[\mathbf{J}^{-1}_{\theta\theta}]_{2,2}-2[\mathbf{J}^{-1}_{\theta\theta}]_{1,2}$ ?

Is it the $CRLB(\theta)?$ I mean, is it the CRLB of estimating both theta’s jointly?

If ${J}_{\theta_1\theta_2}$ were 0, both are independent and the summation will give $CRLB(\theta)=CRLB(\theta_1)+CRLB(\theta_2)$ What if not?

Comment: When describing a CRLB of a vector of parameters ${\theta} = [\theta_1, \theta_2]$ you need to describe it in terms of matrices since the variance structure in this case would be the covariance matrix.

In other words, if $T(X)$ is your unbiased estimator of $\theta$ then the CRLB satisfies

$$ cov(T(X)) \geq I^{-1}(\theta) $$

Where $I^{-1}(\theta)$ is the information matrix and $\geq$ is the relation $A\geq B$ if $A-B$ is positive semi definite. You can find more information on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Multivariate_case).

Comment: @Josh: Hmmm... how about the following argument then:
$\|\boldsymbol\theta-\hat{\boldsymbol\theta}\|^2=\|\theta_1-\hat{\theta}_1\|^2+\|\theta_2-\hat{\theta}_2\|^2$. Then $CRLB(\boldsymbol\theta)=CRLB(\theta_1)+CRLB(\theta_2)$

Comment: But that is not the joint variance. The CRLB is a statement about the variance, not the sum of the MSEs.